# WebStorm does not update file references

Tags: typescript, webstorm

WebStorm 2021.3.1 does not update TypeScript file references after moving a file. Not update in menu refactoring, after drag-and-drop. In previous version after drag-and-drop all files was resolving reference.

tsconfig

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": false,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@business/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@business-test/*": ["src/test-data/mock/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is bug, you need to restart soft. If it does not solve your problem, then remove .idea folder in project folder, and after it will start again indexing file trees.

Comment: @TuralRzaxanov, thanks, for comment. But it's not working. I deleted .idea, updated WS (i have WebStorm 2021.3.3) but it problem have stated

Comment: please create a ticket in youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB, attaching a sample project the issue can be repeated with. Normally references are updated if the IDE can resolve the original file location in import statements

Comment: @lena thanks, will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need turn on search reference when to movie file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLK3E.png)